# How to catch how long Jenkins node is running up

Tags: plugins, time, jenkins

I have to write script on bash linux where i can see how long my nodes were running and if it more than one hour and build run on it i will stay it in up status. If it lower than 50 minutes an no builds than  turn it off. So at first step i can't get time, how long node is running up. Is in Jenkins plugins or any env. variables which show node run time?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread, you could get the data from the statistics.

http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/How-to-Determine-Slave-Up-Down-Time-td4083878.html